# Prove: If A is invertible, then adj(A) is invertible and $[\operatorname{adj}(A)]^{-1}=\frac1{\det(A)}A=\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

> Prove: $\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}$If $A$ is invertible, then $\adj(A)$ is invertible and $[\adj(A)]^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}A=\adj(A^{-1})$

I can show the left side:

\begin{align*}
A^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\adj(A)\\
\implies AA^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\det(A)}A \cdot \adj(A)\\
\implies I&=\frac{1}{\det(A)}A\cdot \adj(A),
\end{align*}
and,
\begin{align*}
A^{-1}A&=\adj(A)\frac{1}{\det(A)}A\\
\implies I&=\adj(A)\frac{1}{\det(A)}A.
\end{align*}
So,
$$[\adj(A)]^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}A.$$

**But I'm not sure how to show:** $$\frac{1}{\det(A)}A=\adj(A^{-1}).$$

Comment: $$adj(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{det(A^{-1})} A^{-1}$$
The left side gives you an expression of $A^{-1}$. Can you proceed then?

Comment: I don't see where this is going? It says: $$adj(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(A)}A$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\adj(A)$$
So,

\begin{align*}
(A^{-1})^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\det(A^{-1})}\adj(A^{-1})\\
\iff A&=\frac{1}{\det(A^{-1})}\adj(A^{-1})\\
\iff \det(A^{-1})A &=\adj(A^{-1})\\
\iff \frac{1}{\det(A)}A&=\adj(A^{-1}).
\end{align*}